# Can I create a repo from my gists?

Tags: git, github, github-api, gist

I've made a bunch of gists (that are related). Is there a simple (or any ) way to create a repo from  the gists through a UI or command line tool?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub automatically creates a git repo for every gist you have. There should be a link to clone each gist on their pages.

If you want to bring multiple gists into one new repository and preserve history, create a new repo, clone your gists, and perform a [subtree merge](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging). If you don't need the histories, just download the files form the gists, create a new repo, and copy and commit in the old files.

Comment: Is there a way I can do this "bulk download" with a simple command? (I dont think it would make sense to have one though, since each of the gists are individual repositories).

Comment: Unfortunately, `git clone` only lets you pass one URL to clone at a time, and GitHub doesn't seem to offer a batch downloader either. You can get around the former issue by using a `for` loop in bash.

Comment: [Here is an example.](https://gist.github.com/nicolasmccurdy/5fc39e28d9b544d472e1)